# javascript document.getelement not working

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript. I am trying to place value on one input field. But it is not working, I don't know why..

```
document.getElementById("c_add").value='sssssss';
```

in the text area with id "c_add", I supposed that value will place as "sssssss", but it is not setting any value..

Full Code:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("c_add").value='sssssss';
</script>

<textarea name="c_add" id="c_add"></textarea>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML as well?

Comment: Have you first read: "[Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById()` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/82548?)"

Comment: Impossible to help you without more context.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks. Now I got what was my fault

Comment: Then I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried do like this?

```
<input type="text" id="mytext">

<script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.getElementById("mytext");
elem.value = "My default value";
</script>
```